# How to import sextante(processing) for QGIS 1.9 (2.0)

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, sextante-qgis-plugin

In the current QGIS development snapshot the SEXTANTE toolbox has been merged into QGIS and is now known as "processing". This is a good step, but the previous import command doesn't work anymore.

```
from sextante.core.Sextante import Sextante # returns an import error
```

How can i import the sextante bindings in current development versions and the upcoming QGIS 2.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
```

and

```
from processing.core.ProcessingConfig import Setting, ProcessingConfig
```

From what I can see, every occurrence of `Sextante` should be replaced with `Processing` and every occurrence of `sextante` with `processing`

Comment: thanks,but the errors carry on. Do you know what about `from processing.core.SextanteConfig import Setting, SextanteConfig` ? Has anyone posted an overview with the new locations?

Comment: Answer updated...