# Import processing in qgis 2.0

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing

I know that this question has already asked but no concrete answer has given!!
My environment is Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm using eclipse-pydev as IDE.

Comment: could you be a bit more specific? what do you want to import?

Comment: Hi. thanks. I just want to run some processing functions like: processing.runalg("grass:r.slope.aspect",...)

Comment: Please add the comment to your question, and you might reference the previous question with a link, also outlining any differences in your question.  If there is no difference we should close this question and edit the previous to promote it back to active and hope for a solution.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70645/how-to-import-sextanteprocessing-for-qgis-1-9-2-0?rq=1